# Change middle mouse button in Sublime Text

Tags: mouse, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

On Sublime Text running on Windows the Middle Mouse button acts as select range, on Linux its Shift+Right click.  How can I set the middle mouse button to be select range on Linux? Specifically Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to create a custom mouse map in Linux and add the relevant bindings that define the Windows behavior. In Sublime, create a new file with JSON syntax and the following contents:

```js
[
    // Mouse 3 column select
    {
        "button": "button3",
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
    },
    {
        "button": "button3", "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "additive": true}
    },
    {
        "button": "button3", "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "subtractive": true}
    }
]
```

Then, save the file as `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap`. You should now be able to mimic the Windows middle mouse functionality in Linux.

**Notes:**

- This will work with both Sublime Text 2 and 3.
- For OS X, the path to save the file is `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap` (note the `OSX` in the parentheses instead of `Linux`).

Comment: It worked seconds after saving the file. Thank you :)

Comment: You sir are a genius and a life saver!

Comment: It works but only when I copy it from config folder to `/opt/sublime_text/Data/Packages/User`, but still thanks. Ubuntu.

Comment: Got me close; I had to create this file in `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages/User` (Linux Mint). Thanks!